# Android license status unknown - Flutter other related issue

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart

Running 'flutter doctor -v' will cause that issue in the title.
The issue 'X Android license status unknown.'

1. I try the following command, and this must fixed the issue but not working:
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   Error : Could not find or load main class blahblah.....
2. I also downloaded and installed the latest SDK tools and obsolete sdk's and the error still the same.
   Error : Could not find or load main class blahblah.....
3. I also add the JAVA_HOME in environment variable

but same errors.

Comment: Please don't put the answer to a question within the question. Instead, add it as your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fixed :
Hope this solution will help for other having the same problem.
First check SDK location username has a space like for example:
C:\User\Juan Dela Cruz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

That is I notice on my username in windows. I change the 'Juan Dela Cruz' to 'JuanDelaCruz' without space following this step:
Method 1: Please follow the steps to rename the user account.

In the search box, type user accounts and click on User Accounts.
Click on “Change your account name”
If it’s prompting for password please enter and click on Yes. If you do not have password click on Yes.
Enter the new user name.
Click on change name.
Method 2:

Note: Before you start, please back up all you data and create a system restore point first.

Press Windows Key + R combination and then type netplwiz in the Run dialog box. Click OK. If prompted for UAC, click Yes.
Now in the User Accounts window, check Users must enter a user name and password to enter this computer, if it is unchecked.
In the User Name section, select the user name to which you want to change the name and click Properties.
In the Properties window, in the User name field, provide the desired user name. Then click Apply followed by OK.
Reboot to see the change.
Change User Folder name: Even after you change the username using this method, your personal folder will continue to display the old username. To rename the user folder, do the following.

1. Create a system restore point first. Then open Registry Editor and navigate to the following key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
2. You will find several folders here like S-1-5-. Search through them till you find a ProfileImagePath pointing to your old username. Double-click on it and replace your old username with your new username.
3. Restart your computer to see the change.

After doing this, I run the 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' and allows me to accept the sdk licenses.

Hope this will help you if we have same issue.

Thanks